# Конкатенация с помощью zipWith

Tags: функции, haskell, функциональное-программирование

Почему нельзя использовать конкатенацию, при вызове подобной конструкции?

```
λ > zipWith (++) [4,5] [5,6]

<interactive>:39:1: error:
• Non type-variable argument in the constraint: Num [a]
  (Use FlexibleContexts to permit this)
• When checking the inferred type
    it :: forall a. Num [a] => [[a]]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Потому, что выражение эквивалентно `[4 ++ 5, 5 ++ 6]`, а оператор `++` определен только для списков.

В зависимости от того, какой результат вы планируете получить, можно сделать так

```hs
Prelude> zipWith (++) [[4],[5]] [[5],[6]]
[[4,5],[5,6]]
```

или так

```hs
Prelude> (++) [4,5] [5,6]
[4,5,5,6]
Prelude> [4,5] ++ [5,6]
[4,5,5,6]
```